# Blue stains from water

Tags: bathroom, tub

What would cause blue stains and a blue tint to our bathroom tub and sink have water purification system in use for aprox. 7 yrs. Does this need any maintence

Comment: Duplicate? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/why-do-i-have-blue-water-coming-out-of-the-faucets

Comment: @NiallC. I don't think so. Blue green stains usually show up with no tint in the water itself.

Answer (score 2):

Blue or blue-green stains in fixtures is a sign of reduced copper. The source of this can be in the water itself (usually well water) or from the plumbing, usually caused by a very low pH (acidic water) which causes deterioration of the plumbing.

This is an [article](http://www.ct.gov/dph/lib/dph/environmental_health/pdf/06_copper_in_private_drinking_water_wells.pdf) describing the problem. You should get the water tested and have a qualified water treatment specialist or plumber come up with a plan to address it.

Since you already have a water treatment system, it may just be out of balance.  In general, these systems require regular maintenance (flushing and changing of catalysts/chemicals).

Get it fixed. It's a health issue.